# How can i convert double[][] array to String[][] array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, double

I work on it but i can't do that.This code has address output i want to convert to string array from double array. What is wrong with this code.

```
public static String[][] getStrings(double[][] a) {
    double[][] c = { {2.0, 3.1,3,7}, {1.5,5.8,9.6,1} };
    String[][] s2d = new String[c.length][c.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < s2d.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<s2d[i].length;j++){
            s2d[i][j]=String.valueOf(c);
            System.out.println(s2d);
        }
    }
    return s2d;
}
```

This is the output that i have:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;2a139a55
[[Ljava.lang.String;2a139a55
[[Ljava.lang.String;2a139a55
[[Ljava.lang.String;2a139a55
[[Ljava.lang.String;2a139a55
```

Comment: Please post any compiler errors, exception stack traces, or incorrect output you have.

Comment: May I ask?  Just what do you think is happening with this statement: "`s2d[i][j]=String.valueOf(c);`"?

Comment: This is the way to print the array `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(s2d));`.

Comment: i tried to implement string array's values to the double array's.

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware of deepToString. Editing my answer to reference that instead of just toString. Thanks @PaulBoddington

Comment: i tried 'System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(s2d));' also but output did not change

Comment: Did you also include changes from @John Bollinger's answer?

Comment: Yes i did the changes

Comment: https://ideone.com/QXvU0H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in this code. Here is a solution, more intuitive than what you have and will releave you from headache.

---

### Explanation

Within your method, you create a new `String` array of arrays with as much arrays as contained in your `double[][]` parameter. As the sizes of each array can vary, we are not initializing it.

```
new String[a.length][];
```

Then, we loop over all the arrays of doubles, convert them to `String` using [`Arrays#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double[])) (we trim the `"[" "]"` that are the first and last character of the output of this method) and split it to have an array of Strings.

---

### Solution

```
public static String[][] getStrings(double[][] a) {
    String[][] output = new String[a.length][];
    int i = 0;
    for (double[] d : a){
        output[i++] = Arrays.toString(d).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
    }
    return output;
}
```

---

### Input

```
public static void main(String[]a) {
    double[][] ds = { { 2.0, 3.1, 3, 7 }, { 1.5, 5.8, 9.6, 1 } };
    for (String[] s : getStrings(ds)){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    }
}
```

---

### Output

```
[2.0,  3.1,  3.0,  7.0]
[1.5,  5.8,  9.6,  1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] s2d = new String[c.length][c.length];
```

Should be

```
String[][] s2d = new String[c.length][c[0].length];
```

You are going outside of your bound as you are creating a 2x2 matrix instead of a 2x4

Also, Arrays by nature of Java do not have pretty prints.
Use [Arrays.deepToString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])) to properly output an array. Fixed per @PaulBoddington's comment.

Comment: i did that but i got same output again.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your code, but the one that leads directly to the unexpected output / result is that this ...

```
               s2d[i][j]=String.valueOf(c);
```

... should be ...

```
               s2d[i][j] = String.valueOf(c[i][j]);
```

Comment: i did that too but result did not change.

Comment: Good catch, missed that one. But this still will have the same output since an array's toString method is the type + its id

Comment: @mascoj well, no, because `c[i][j]` is the array element, a `double`.  It's `String` value has what I presume to be the expected form.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. @mancini13 didn't have an Arrays.toString, he was just printing the array itself. The default array toString method (the one provided through Object) just outputs "[[L<type>;id". In this case "[[Ljava.lang.String;2a139a55"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little strange... for example you are taking in double[][] a as an argument but never use it.
By the way, the reason you are getting "address output" is because you are setting every variable in s2d to the String with the value of the array c instead of the single doubles.

To solve your problem you should be using

`s2d[i][j] = String.valueOf(a[i][j]);` instead of `s2d[i][j]=String.valueOf(a);`

Answer (score 0):

````
## ----------


#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line,line0[99];
    double ele[99];
     getline(cin,line);
    for (int x = 0;x <= line.length();x++)
    {
        if (line[x] == ' ')
        {
            step++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            line0[step] += line[x];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < size_; i++)
    {
        string vo = line0[i];
        ele[i] += stof(vo);
    }
}
```
 ##
````

Comment: The question is *clearly* about Java yet you have posted C++ code.